# "TS2729 [ERROR]: Property 'boundary' used before its initialization" in extern library

Tags: deno

After updating my deno version to 1.9 today I had started having the following problem when running my tests or my scripts:

```
TS2729 [ERROR]: Property 'boundary' is used before its initialization.
  readonly dashBoundary = encoder.encode(`--${this.boundary}`);
                                               ~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.63.0/mime/multipart.ts:266:52

'boundary' is declared here.
  constructor(reader: Deno.Reader, private boundary: string) {
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.63.0/mime/multipart.ts:269:36
```

I checked and I am not using the mime repository anywhere in my code, instead some other repositories must use it.

I am using the following repositories:

1. x/abc
2. std/uuid
3. std/fs
4. std/path
5. std/fmt
6. std/testing

I made sure that I am explicitely using the newest version for all of the imports of the std library (std version 0.93.0).

When I am running the files that are importing the std library (instead of running the entire application) no errors occur.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the repository `x/abc` was the problem.

I did not add a version when importing it implicitly. When importing implicitly it in the following way it worked:

```
import abc from "https://deno.land/x/abc@v1.3.1/mod.ts";
```